# Looping through a text file, readline() construction fails on large files

Tags: python, file-io

In Python 2.6 and 2.7 I would have thought that these two constructs would be identical:

**Method A**

```
i=0
f=open('fred.txt','r')
for line in f.readline():
    i+=1
print i
```

**Method B**

```
i=0
f=open('fred.txt','r')
for line in f:
    i+=1
print i
```

However, when fred.txt grew to be 74,000 lines, with each line 2,684 characters in length, **Method A** prints 2685  while **Method B** prints 74000.  Obviously, Method B is preferred, but why does Method A work for small files but fail for large files?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There’s a typo, it should be `f.readlines()`. You’re reading one line and looping through each character in the line.

Both methods (`readlines` vs iterating over the file directly) ought to give the same results, but `readlines` will store the entire contents in memory.

Comment: Looking back at the edit history it was readlines() originally, but changed to readline to avoid reading the entire file into memory.  Stupid mistake the should have been caught in testing.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: So to be clear, iterating over the file (NOT readlines()) will only cause one line at a time to be read? My file is 26 GB > 12 GiB memory...